# Linear Algebra: Suppose A is n x m, and n < m. Show that A'A is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having trouble showing that $A'A$ is singular (non-invertible) if $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix with $n < m$.

Any help?

Comment: Do you know anything about the rank of a matrix?

Comment: Yes, the number of non-zero rows in the row echelon form.

Comment: Good, that's the definition. Now, do you know any properties? In particular, how rank of $B$ and rank of $BC$ and $CB$ relate.

Comment: Any thoughts? Rank of product of two matrices is not greater than...

Comment: Ah, yes. Sketchy proof? Rank (A'A) <= min(Rank A', Rank A). Rank (A) <= n, so Rank(A'A) <= n (< m) so A'A is not full rank

Comment: Ask yourself: can a matrix map from a lower dimensional space to a higher dimensional space so that every member of the higher dimensional space is an image of some element of the lower dimensional space? Specifically, A' maps from n dimensions to m dimensions.

Comment: @Brian, it is even true that $\text{rank}\,{A'A}=\text{rank}\,{A}$, but it doesn't really matter. Indeed, it is a proof.

Comment: @Brian Your answer in your comment is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A_{n\times m} and $B_{m\times n}$ are two matrices where $n>m$. $Let $AB$ be a invertible matrix. Then, one can see that $|AB|\neq 0$. By |A|, we mean determinant of matrix $A$. Now, we add zero to matrices $A$ and $B$. We have following matrices:

$A'_{m\times m}=\left[ \begin{array}{ccr} a_{11} & ... & a_{1n} \\ . & ... & .\\a_{n1}&...&a_{nm}\\0&...&0 \end{array} \right] $ and $B'_{m\times m}=\left[ \begin{array}{ccr} b_{11} & ... & b_{1n} \\ . & ... & .\\b_{n1}&...&b_{nm}\\0&...&0 \end{array} \right] $

Now, one can see $A'B'=AB$, but $|A'|=|B'|=0$. It is a contradiction.

Comment: The idea might work, but the execution is flawed. The upper right entry in $A'$ should be $a_{1m}$, the $b_{n1}$ in $B'$ should be $b_{m1}$, both matrices should be extended to $n\times n$ (not $m\times m$, as you have written $n\gt m$), and one of them needs added columns of zeros, not rows. Also, there's a formatting problem in the 1st sentence.